# Not all data imported using PHP importing data from MSSQL to MySQL

Tags: php

I am trying to import data from one DB(MSSQL) to another DB(MySQL)
The code bellow has worked for me before but now I have run into a problem.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
$country = "LV";
$DBServer="localhost";
$DBUser="root";
$DBPass="root";
$DBName="inventory";
$conn2 = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);

$query = 'TRUNCATE TABLE Items';
$result=$conn2->query($query);


mysqli_set_charset($conn2,"utf8");
$connectorpol = new NavisionExtractorPol();
$country = "POL";
$mssqlres = $connectorpol->getQueryResults('SELECT sbcode, bcode, descr FROM [dbo].[L_Items]');
var_dump($mssqlres);
while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($mssqlres)) {
$query1 = "INSERT INTO Items(sbcode, bcode, descr, country) VALUES ('" . $row["sbcode"] . "', '" .
    $row["bcode"] . "', '" .
    $row["descr"] . "', '" . $country . "')";

$result2=$conn2->query($query1);
if(!$result2){
    echo $result2->error;
  }
}
```

The problem is that not all rows from MSSQL are imported from 7820 only 7802 are imported. Any Ideas why?

Comment: Any specific errors ?

Comment: No! that is the problem. There are no errors. And I have tested that It loops through all 7820 rows but the inserted row count is lower.

Comment: Do you have `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on your script?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i did not notice the symbols in the rows that i am inserting.
The queries contained ' symbol and by doing so it messed up the query and it made it no executable.